# Is possible to get geolocation from BlackBerry WiFi using javascript?

Tags: javascript, blackberry, geolocation

I'm try to use my javascript to get the current geolocation of blackberry, but in that method is always handle the error block.

This is my javascript :

```
function getCurrentPosition() {

    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(

            function( position ) {
                alert(position.coords.latitude + ', ' +position.coords.longitude);
            },

            function( error ) {
                alert( "Something went wrong: ", error );
            },

            {
                timeout: (10 * 1000)
            }

        );

    }
    else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
```

In that method is always alert the message "Something went wrong: ".

**NOTE** : I'm using Blackberry 9780 with WiFi only

Thanks

Comment: Do you have sim inserted? I think it's possible to get satellite fix over wifi but not in 10 seconds. The cold start of GPS could take around minute on the old devices.

Comment: I'm using WiFi only, not sim inserted. I already try with more than 1 minute but it still not.

Comment: just remember that it's not possible to get satellite GPS indoors

Comment: does this work for you? http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/ try this test page http://www.merkwelt.com/people/stan/geo_js/sample.html the libray handles some fringe cases, maybe your cell fits one of them.

Comment: I already tried that, but The problem is like @Eugen said, because we need to inserted the SIM and the timeout need to be around 1 minute + need to be outdoors. these 3 points will work fine.